# Entity framework where and like c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to convert this query to entity framework query in c#

```
 Select id 
 From cachieroperation 
 Where activation_start < GETDATE() AND activation_end > GETDATE() 
       AND last_used+'0:8:0'< GETDATE() 
       AND skipass_number like 'DA3C12DC2186018220%'
```

Comment: query = select id from cachieroperation where activation_start<GETDATE() and activation_end>GETDATE() and last_used+'0:8:0'< GETDATE() and skipass_number like 'DA3C12DC2186018220%'

Comment: here is a good tutorial you should keep at your disposal 
[C# MSDN Linq query examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    var query =  from a in cachieroperation 
    where a.activation_start < now && a.activation_end > now 
       && a.last_used < now.AddMinutes(-8) && a.skipass_number.Contains('DA3C12DC2186018220')
    select id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure to use the date in the server, use SqlFunctions.GetDate():

```
var result = from co in context.CachierOperations
             where co.ActivationStart < SqlFunctions.GetDate() &&
                   co.ActivationEnd > SqlFunctions.GetDate() &&
                   co.LastUsed.AddMinutes(8) < SqlFunctions.GetDate() &&
                   co.SkiPassNumber.Contains("DA3C12DC2186018220")
             select co.Id;
```